# The POS Device is not connecting, how can I undestand wether the cable or the code is wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, connection, pos

I want to connect to an Ingenico iCT250 POS device through a c# package. I am using [this one](https://github.com/F4pl0/ingenico-pos-dotnet-lib) . I followed the instructions on their readme and tried to connect. When I run, after a few seconds the program closes and I got this message.

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\c#\pos\pos\bin\Debug\net6.0\pos.exe (process 22480) exited with code 0.
```

I don't understand why I got this exit code. What is happening?
Is the code wrong? Or there are problems with the cable? How can I research a solution?
Or is it connected because I read that "Saying that the Process finished with exit code 0 means that everything worked ok."? But if everything was okay, the `posDevice.IsConnected`
should have returned either `true` or `false`.
I tried also with passing the port only in new POS. But same result.
Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
        POS posDevice = new POS("COM4", 115200);
         posDevice.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine("IsConnected??", posDevice.IsConnected);
    }
}
```

Comment: i suggest adding a `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of your Main-method, so the program _doesn't exit once it's done,_ so you can see the output. and you might also edit your WriteLine-call so it actually can output the value: `Console.WriteLine("IsConnected?? {0}", posDevice.IsConnected); `

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this doesn't help me to understand the problem. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: `exited with code 0.` means: _nothing went wrong_. so your code worked (didn't throw an exception etc.), wrote a string (that _doesn't_ contain your boolean because you did not add a placeholder for it) and then _was done_ and closed the console it wrote to. whichis why you don't see what it wrote to the console. that's what my suggestions are trying to change: 1) stop the program from exiting immediatelly and closing the console window, and 2) actually writing `IsConnected` to the console. **another suggestion** would be: use the debugger, _step through your code_, inspect the variable.

Comment: If you add your comment as an answer, I can assign it as response! Now I understand, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exited with code 0.` means that *nothing went wrong* with your code (in terms of Exceptions).

but there's two *logical* problems with your code:

1 - you're not actually writing the result of your test, because you didn't include a placeholder in your format.

so try changing it to:
`Console.WriteLine("IsConnected?? {0}", posDevice.IsConnected);`

2 - after your program is done, it *immediately exits* - closing the console window, and hiding the output from you.

so add the following to the end of your `Main`:
`Console.ReadLine();`

that way, your program waits for your user input before exiting, keeping the console window open for you to read the result.

the code in total:

```cs
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
        POS posDevice = new POS("COM4", 115200);
        posDevice.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine("IsConnected?? {0}", posDevice.IsConnected);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
        POS posDevice = new POS("COM4", 115200);

        posDevice.Connect();

        if (posDevice.IsConnected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device is connected");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device is not connected");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And check the other methods in the "POS" class, which may be useful to troubleshoot the connection issues.